# Configure TLS cipher negotiation priority in Firefox/Thunderbird

Tags: security, firefox, ssl, thunderbird

Is it possible to configure TLS cipher negotiation **priority** in Firefox/Thunderbird by choosing the most secure which is available on both sides? Now the situation is that even if TLSv1.3 is available on server and client side - Firefox for some reason chooses TLSv1.2.

Of course, we can set at `about:config` `security.tls.version.min` and `security.tls.version.max` to **4**, but still a lot of web servers supports only TLSv1.2.

To check available cipher suites on client side:

```
# openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
# openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 443 -www
```

Then open browser `https://localhost`

To check available cipher suites on server side:

```
# openssl version
```

Should be at latest version for TLSv1.3: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

```
# openssl s_client -tls1_3 -ciphersuites 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' -connect somehost.com:443
```

Or with nmap - but currently TLSv1.3 not supported:

```
# nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 somehost.com
```

As a prove - if server is configured to use only these cipher suites:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Firefox chooses weaker one - `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.

Noticed, that on Thunderbird 68.0b5 (64-bit) priority is set to higher cipher, as should be.